# Why didn't Bruce Banner simply tell this character that "I am NOT single"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-incredible-hulk, avengers-age-of-ultron

In the *Avengers: Age of Ultron* movie,

> Bruce Banner initially avoided Natasha's flirts. And then, he rejected Natasha's relationship proposal by saying that he couldn't reproduce.

But,

> it didn't work at all. She continued flirting with him.

From *The Incredible Hulk* movie, we know that Bruce Banner already has a Girl named Betty. Why didn't he simply tell the girl that he wasn't single, and she wasn't allowed to flirt?

Is Bruce Banner still in relationship with Betty? What do official statements say as they aren't pushing new Hulk movies in MCU?

Comment: @Nerrolken I reverted your title edit. Your proposed title was meaningless ("Why didn't Bruce Banner try this?"). The current title is not a spoiler, regardless of what the user says in his/her profile. If you disagree, let's discuss it in meta.

Comment: @AndresF. Meta [discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/6865/20221) created.

Comment: Did you see *Incredible Hulk*? Kind of the whole point is that he can’t go near the woman he loved, because he might Hulk out and hurt her. It’s safe to say, particularly as she’s not mentioned at all, that by the time of Avengers 1 she’s not a part of his life.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite But, in the end, he did controlled himself. Read the question carefully...

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433: the question doesn’t say anything about him controlling himself, so I think I read it carefully enough.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I meant that Hulking out thing happened before he controlled himself. (sorry, it's not in question. I referred to another question. Currently, I am zapped by loads of notifications) If you can prove that he still Hulk out with her, that can be answer.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433: cool cool, no worries. But I don’t think proof that Banner could Hulk out when near Betty is required to answer this question. There’s no evidence that they’re still in a relationship after the end of *The Incredible Hulk*, and given that Banner left her town and she’s never mentioned, it’s safe to assume they’re not.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your question is based on the premise that Bruce and Betty are still together; the most obvious and likely answer, based on the facts, is that they aren't.

Bruce left Betty at the end of *The Incredible Hulk*, when he ran off to his remote hut to try and gain control of the Hulk part of himself. Since then, we haven't seen any indication that the two of them are together. In particular, there have been several situations where *other* Avenger's significant others were brought up, where it would have made sense for Betty Ross to also be mentioned:

- In *The Avengers*, Coulson makes a point to say that Jane Foster has been taken somewhere safe, for Thor's benefit
- In *Age of Ultron*, both Thor and Tony mention their respective girlfriends (likely to explain why they weren't in the movie)

In neither case does anyone ever mention Betty Ross, which to me stands out as a rather notable omission.

Based on his actions in *Age of Ultron*, especially

> his conversation with Natasha in the Barton house, where he lists all of the reasons he can't ever have a long-term relationship with a woman

it seems very, very likely that he left Betty "for her own good". (This is a classic part of the superhero's tragic backstory: they get to save the world but they don't get to have a normal life.)

Comment: Interestingly, we recently learnt that General Ross would be in *Captain America: Civil War*. Although we have no news on the return of Betty, I would hope that she gets mentioned in some capacity.

Answer (score 10):

In the first Avengers movie they found him living in a hut, where was Betty then? She isn't specifically mentioned as far as I am aware and she doesn't seem to be in the picture anymore.

Comment: He didn't permanently settle there in Calcutta. Also, they didn't show Betty, it doesn't mean she wasn't around.

Comment: Does it really make sense that he would have a girlfriend there with him and he would just leave her without even telling her? He didn't say anything about needing to get some stuff or talk to anyone when they take him. He was out working and then just doesn't show up at home. Doesn't seem like something he would do. I mean sure, he could still be dating Betty. But he could also be dating Spiderman with just as much evidence supporting it at this point.

Comment: Did we she every single detail after Natasha intercepted him? He might have visited her.

Comment: Also, there's this thing called "Long Distance Relationship"..

Comment: If they were doing an LDR then it would have made it too easy to find him, he was trying to be off the grid. You are literally creating things to cling to a theory that has no evidence. I wasn't even joking, there is just as much evidence he is dating Spiderman.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433: “they didn't show Betty, it doesn't mean she wasn't around”. Given that these are fictional characters, it’s a pretty strong indication that she wasn’t around. We can speculate that she was, but as you know, that’s not what this site is for.