# Can Bruce Banner have sex without turning into the Hulk now?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-incredible-hulk

In *The Incredible Hulk*, Bruce Banner had problem having sex with Betty because it was increasing his heart beat rate which would turn him into the Hulk.

But, in the end, he controlled himself. Does that mean he can have sex now? Or, doing Meditation while on the bed is impossible and [it did affect his relationship with Betty](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87494/why-didnt-bruce-banner-simply-tell-natasha-that-i-am-not-single)?

Comment: Only accidentally in a car.

Comment: Of amusing relevance... [This College Humor Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgzh2BeFBQE)

Comment: ... *do sex*... ***do** sex*?

Comment: This is something that bothered  me in Incredible Hulk, since it is anger or distress not excitement or arousal that causes the change.

Answer (score 1):

Unsurprisingly, explicit references to the likelihood of Bruce Banner Hulking out during coitus are no where to be found in any Marvel Cinematic Universe property since *The Incredible Hulk*.

However, during *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, Bruce Banner remarks that it isn't physically possible for him to have kids, leading to;

> Natasha Romanoff, AKA Black Widow revealing that she too is unable to conceive after being sterilised.

As such, it seems safe to assume that the reason for his inability to have kids is the same reason that he couldn't have a physical relationship in *The Incredible Hulk* - that the risk of an episode is simply too high.

It probably is worth mentioning that in the Marvel Comics, The Hulk has fathered a child named Skaar (in the *Planet Hulk* storyline), whereas as far as I am aware Bruce Banner never has.

Comment: Yes, I thought this was the direct implication of that conversation. "Do the math", says Banner. He wasn't informing Nat of some medical news: he was pointing out something that he thought she should find obvious.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I've just now realised that Banner could be referring to the huge amounts of radiation he absorbed when becoming The Hulk for the first time in this scene - he could easily be sterile, or have such messed up DNA that any children he might father could have real genetic problems.

Comment: Yeah, suppose so.

Answer (score 0):

Bruce Banner did conceive a child with Betty. Betty revealed her pregnancy in INCREDIBLE HULK #344. However, an editorial decision made Betty miscarry over the writer's wishes.

http://www.peterdavid.net/2012/12/17/creative-differences-part-1/

Comment: While this is certainly related and helpful, the question was specifically asking about the Marvel Cinematic Universe version (Earth-199999) version.

Comment: You are correct. I meant to flesh out the information posted upthread about whether or not Bruce Banner has ever conceived a child in Marvel Comics. AVENGERS 2 suggests that the film version of Bruce Banner may be sterile.